# Is there an efficient way to "crop" a file (remove x number of bytes from tail)?

Tags: java, file, io

Good afternoon all. I was wondering how do we efficiently remove x number of bytes from the end of a file? (inverse operation of append)

Reading the bytes from the original file and writing them to a new file just doesn't seem right (fast) especially if the file is a huge one.

Is there a way we could possibly set the [file length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29)?

Or rather, what's the best way to "crop" a file?

Comment: I think you can do so (w/o writing to a new file) only if the OS manages file truncation like this (and if it allows outside callers to access such functions which might be part of the kernel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RandomAccessFile.setLength(long newLength)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength%28long%29)

Comment: Are you sure this does not rewrite the contents to a new file?

Comment: Why should it? The documentation states that the file is truncated, which is exactly what is being asked for.

Comment: yes it truncates, but Pacerier wants to make sure the file is not rewritten to another part of the disk (my understanding), but its bytes should reside at the same location. The chopped off bytes should be marked as free space on HDD. Given these assumptions, I'm not sure if anyone can claim that all the JVM implementations will do this when setLength() is called... Just my thoughts. I could be misinterpreting

Comment: Barring really odd filesystem behavior, there's no reason for byte movement when the size is being reduced - or even increased, in most cases. A file doesn't have to be contiguous on disk.

Comment: @tzaman Yes I was looking for a way to simply tell the harddisk the file ends at position x. And most importantly this operation should be fast, the time taken should generally not increase linearly with the size of the file. Do you mean to say that `RandomAccessFile.setLength` is the best option we have?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 answers for you.

- If you don't want to manually read, truncate, and rewrite the file, but you don't care if these operations **might** happen behind the scenes, you can use `setLength(..)` as tzaman pointed out.
- If you don't want the bytes of the file to ever be rewritten to a new disk location (you just want the bytes at the end to be marked as free on disk (side effect: fragmentation)), I don't think it is possible. You would have to see if the underlying OS implements file truncation like this (by talking with the hardware). I am not familiar with such options yet. Furthermore, there are different JVM implementations and there is no guarantee about how they run your code behind the scenes.

Though the biggest problem with the latter approach is fragmentation on disk. The OS might have better ways at organizing the files if they are rewritten somewhere as a whole; but it depends. Maybe you can write your own OS for this specific application. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by writing "own OS" ?

Comment: @Pacerier well I was just throwing it out there for completion... if you really needed this feature (file truncation to be fast) you'd write your own OS to guarantee that it does truncation the way you want it. Then you would run the JVM on this OS, so when you cann some truncate() function your OS does what you need.

Comment: well that's what I'm not understanding. How does that helps us to achieve truncate() on a windows running the Java code?

Comment: @Pacerier you would run java on your OS not on windows